# After calculating a tensor, how can I show it as a image?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, tensorflow

I have one dimensional numpy array. After performing a calculation in TensorFlow, I get a `tf.Tensor` as output. I am trying to reshape it into a 2-dimensional array and show it as an image.

If it were a numpy ndarray, I would know how to plot it as an image. But it is a tensor now!

Although I tried `tensor.eval()` to convert it into numpy array, I got an error saying "No default session".

Can anyone teach me how to show a tensor as an image?

```
... ...
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()    
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# training
for i in range(1):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: x_data.T, y_: y_data.T})

# testing
probability = tf.argmax(y,1);
sess.run(probability, feed_dict={x: x_test.T})

#show result
img_res = tf.reshape(probability,[len_y,len_x])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 1)

# It is the the following line that I do not know how to make it work...
ax.imshow(np.asarray(img_res.eval())) #how to plot a tensor ?#
plt.show()
... ...
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Can you post your attempt(s) ?

Comment: please update the question with good indentation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will make easier to get an answer

Comment: sorry, not familiar with this.. just updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate error you're seeing is because `Tensor.eval()` only works when there is a ["default `Session`"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#get_default_session). This requires that either (i) you're executing in a `with tf.Session():` block, (ii) you're executing in a `with sess.as_default():` block, or (iii) you're using [`tf.InteractiveSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#InteractiveSession).

There are two simple workarounds to make your case work:

```
# Pass the session to eval().
ax.imshow(img_res.eval(session=sess))

# Use sess.run().
ax.imshow(sess.run(img_res))
```

Note that, as a large point about visualizing your image, you might consider using the [`tf.image_summary()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#image_summary) op along with [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) to visualize tensors produced by a larger training pipeline.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to tensorflow. Trying to learn to use it. Very appreciate about your answer